# Shorthand only for if

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write shorthand for an IF statement without else?

```
var val = score == 10 ? win;
console.log(val) //basically I want to update `val` only with the if statement.
```

Comment: Check http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: and what should assigned if not?

Comment: @NinaScholz if not shouldn't update `val` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a logical and:

```
var val;
score == 10 && (val = win);
```

Comment: @Becky: This functions and is an answer to your question, but it's **awful**. (Which is not Nina's fault.) Just use an `if`. Side note: No need for the `()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your comment. What makes you say this answer is awful?

Comment: @Becky: Not the *answer*, just this usage of `&&` (which sadly some people do). It's a flat-out abusage. Hard to read, hard to debug. But that's just opinion. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Understood. Thanks. But it answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Looks like `()` is required to avoid the `:` ternary operator  error.

Comment: the `()` are required, because the assignment throws a `syntax error`

Comment: @NinaScholz: Gah, precedence, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

why not simply

```
var val = score == 10 ? win : val;
```

or

```
var score = 10, val=10, win=11;
score == 10 && ( val = win )
alert( val ); //after this output will be 11
```

Comment: That's cool. Never thught of doing `: val;`. Thanks :) +10

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it shouldn't update the `val` variable if the statement doesn't return `true`, just use the `val` variable as the else:

```
var val = score == 10 ? win: val;
console.log(val)
```

You could also use:

```
score == 10 && var val = win;
```

But I would suggest just using the `if` statement for readability:

```
if(score == 10) 
    var val = win;
```